# Using find_if on std::vector<std::string> with bind2nd and string::compare

Tags: c++, stl

This may seem to be an academic question, but still I would be very interested in the answer:

I have a vector of strings `s` in which I would like to find a given string `findme`. This can be done using something like

```
find(s.begin(), s.end(), findme);
```

My question is: There must be a way doing the same using `find_if` and the `compare` method of the STL strings as predicate, but how? Something like

```
find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), bind2nd(mem_fun_ref(&string::compare), string("findme")) );
```

does not work, because the compare method has several overloads and the compiler does not know which one to choose.

As a second step: My motivation for using find_if instead of find is that I have a vector of objects derived from a class having a string property `name` and I want to find an object with a given name. Is this possible (without writing an extra function to be used as predicate)?

---

EDIT: As some (most :) answers mentioned using Boost -- I would prefer not to have to include Boost for this. (As far as I know, most of the Boost libraries are "only" templates, so there should be a way without using Boost.)

Comment: Not the answer that you are looking for, but for me that's where I draw the line.  If it becomes hard to set up a binding scheme, it is usually hard to debug it when it wasn't completely as you expected.
Having said that, have you already considered boost::bind and boost::lambda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to cast the member function pointer to suitable type. Another thing you are forgetting is that std::string::compare returns 0 for equal strings, so you'll also need to negate the functor. All in all:

```
std::find_if(
    vec.begin(), vec.end(),
    std::not1(
        std::bind2nd(
            std::mem_fun_ref(static_cast<int (std::string::*)(const char*)const>(&std::string::compare)),
            "findme"
        )
    )
);
```

As to your rationale against boost: its templates are an order of a magnitude more flexible than what you can find in STL functional header. It's either boost, you wait for C++0x lambdas (which I believe will be the preferable way in such situations) or you write some helpers yourself. Currently it can't get simpler than:

```
std::find_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(), boost::bind(&X::name, _1) == "findme");
```

FYI, C++0x will add std::bind which is similar to boost::bind but it seems the convenience of overloaded operator== will not be there.

Comment: This doesn't compile! reference to reference problem.

Comment: Right, not with VC++ (OK for MinGW and Comeau online). I changed to use a different overload which shouldn't exhibit the same problem. (I guess the question is really about what to do in precence of overloads and not specifically how to find a string with find_if and string::compare - which is just stupid, as should be clear.)

Comment: One more thing, the presence of overloads is just as much of a problem for boost::bind etc, unless there happens to be another way (such as in this case, using operator== instead of compare).

Answer (score 3):

Select the correct overload yourself.

```
int (string::*compare)(const string&) const;
compare = &string::compare;
find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), bind2nd( mem_fun_ref(compare), string("findme")));
```

But then you get stuck with the reference to reference problem "Item #50 of Effective STL".
And the boost.Bind lib or boost.Lambda is the solution for that.

```
int (string::*compare)(const string&) const;
compare = &string::compare;
find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), bind(compare, _1, "findme")==0);
```

Or

```
find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), bind2nd(std::equal_to<string>(), string("findme")));
```

Comment: The last version is the cleanest and most readable version of all of these answers. No wonder it didn't get any votes ;)

Answer (score 1):

If a function has overloaded functions, you can cast the function to correct signature like
`(void (*)(int,int))(&f)`.

For your second question, if you use boost, you can do something like this,

```
find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), boost::bind(std::equal_to<string>(), boost::bind(&SomeClass::name, _1), name);
```

Comment: boost::bind overloads a few operators for convenience, so the "equal_to" par of your example can be replaced by using operator==: boost::bind(&SomeClass::name, _1) == name which is more readable

Comment: I thought that was only in boost::lambda. I agree it is more readable in this case, but i was just trying to demonstrate how to use boost::bind

Comment: The original version of boost::bind did not have those operator overloads, but "recent" (from 1.33) versions have: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/bind/bind.html#operators

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that the syntax rapidly gets unweildy, if you are trying to call several functions together. Did you try something like this?

```
find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), bind2nd(mem_fun_ref(&string::compare), "findme"));
```

Does this not match the `char *` overload?

Comment: The problem really lies in the expression `mem_fun_ref(&string::compare)`. How do you pass a overloadset of functions to `mem_fun_ref` ?